# Extending std::to_string to support enums and pointers

Tags: c++

I have the following template function `ToString` that uses `std::to_string` for arithmetic types and tries doing a `static_cast` for pointer and enum types.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
std::string ToString(T val)
{
    if (std::is_arithmetic<T>::value)
    {
        return std::to_string(val);
    }

    if (std::is_enum<T>::value || std::is_pointer<T>::value)
    {
        return std::to_string(static_cast<size_t>(val));
    }
}

enum class MyEnum : int
{
    E1,
    E2
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyEnum e = MyEnum::E1;
    const void* ptr = &e;

    std::cout << ToString(e) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ToString(ptr) << std::endl;
}
```

The code above doesn't compile. Is there a way I can achieve the desired functionality?

The compilation errors on VS2017 are

```
Error   C2440   'static_cast': cannot convert from 'T' to 'size_t'
Error   C2665   'std::to_string': none of the 9 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The code doesn't have any of the necessary `#include` directives. Add them in and if it still doesn't compile include the error messages.

Comment: Q is different but answer is exactly right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55341631/polymorphism-in-template-functions

Comment: What's meant to happen if non of the conditions in `ToString` are true?

Comment: For one, you're trying to mix *compile-time* semantics with *run-time* behavior. Ex: if `T` is arithmetic, then just use `return std::to_string(val);`, otherwise... yeah, that line of code *still* has to compile. Think of is this way: `if (true) { return std::to_string(val);` and `if (false) { return std::to_string(val); }` are the two possible outcomes here, and *both* need to compile. I think you're looking for an sfinae solution instead.

Comment: a. Use constexpr if (or tag dispatch) b. Your function is missing return when neither is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `if constexpr`. Otherwise you instantiate `std::to_string` with a pointer or enum, which fails to compile (C2665).

Futhermore you cannot static cast pointer to an integer (C2440). You need reinterpret cast.

Also, your function lacks a return if the passed argument is neither enum, pointer nor an arithmetic type. In such case the behaviour is undefined. Solution: Always return something (or fail compilation if template arguments are invalid).

Also, `size_t` is not guaranteed to be large enough to represent all pointer values. you want `std::uintptr_t`.

And you'll probably want to use `std::underlying_type_t` to get the correct type for `enum class`.

```
if constexpr (std::is_pointer<T>::value) {
    return std::to_string(reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(val));
} else if constexpr (std::is_enum<T>::value)
{
    return std::to_string(static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<T>>(val));
} else {
    return std::to_string(val);
}
```

Once you add the missing headers, this should work.

P.S. Design note: Now printing a pointer, integer or enum are all identical in output. You might want to add some prefix or similar to disambiguate the result.

Comment: Nice solution. Notable: break out your C++17 toolchain for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the immediate issue here is the `static_cast` if T is a pointer type. To convert a pointer to an integer, you need to use a `reinterpret_cast` rather than a `static_cast`, since that cast fundamentally reinterprets the bits of the pointer variable as a number rather than simply telling C++ to change what kind of object if thinks is being pointed at.

As the comments have pointed out, you’ll likely need to do some restructuring on your code to get it to work correctly, because when you instantiate the template, all the code in the body of the function will be compiled with that choice of T. To add to the list of suggestions of how to do this, if you’re using a C++17 compiler, consider using `if constexpr` in your code instead of a regular `if`. This will tell C++ to only conditionally compile the different branches of the if/else chain.

Answer (score 1):

This works with c++11.  I hacked it together so I thought I may as well post it.  You should pay attention to the other answers here though.

```
#include <cstdint>                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#include <string>                                                                                                                                                                                                    
#include <type_traits>                                                                                                                                                                                               
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                                  

template <typename T>                                                                                                                                                                                                
auto ToString(T val) -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, std::string>::type                                                                                                                     
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        return std::to_string(val);                                                                                                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

template <typename T>                                                                                                                                                                                                
auto ToString(T val) -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, std::string>::type                                                                                                                           
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        return std::to_string(static_cast<typename std::underlying_type<T>::type>(val));                                                                                                                                                             
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                    


template <typename T>                                                                                                                                                                                                
auto ToString(T val) -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value, std::string>::type                                                                                                                        
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        return std::to_string(reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(val));                                                                                                                                                        
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

enum class MyEnum : int                                                                                                                                                                                              
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        E1,                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        E2                                                                                                                                                                                                           
};                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

int main(int argc, char* argv[])                                                                                                                                                                                     
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        MyEnum e = MyEnum::E1;                                                                                                                                                                                       
        const void* ptr = &e;                                                                                                                                                                                        

        std::cout << ToString(e) << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                       
        std::cout << ToString(ptr) << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                     
}
```